# silverlight sample not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, silverlight-5.0

I wanted give another chance to silverlight, so I started reading the tutorials on the silverlight.net site.
Unfortunately, I have found a sample, that works in IE9, Chrome, Opera and Safari, but not in Firefox 14. Link to the sample: [link](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/what-is-silverlight/xaml-%28silverlight-quickstart%29) (sample with blue rectangle)

Isn't the plugin fully cross browser?

In the Channel9, the Silverlight player have problems in Firefox too. I can start playing the screencast, but I can't stop it or scroll (the first link from the shore: [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-85-Windows-Azure-Sample-Content-Review)). To watch something there, I must use IE.

Are there any resources showing, why in Firefox there are such problems?

[edit]
Now I see,the sample with red/yellow rectangle doesn't work too on Firefox..

Comment: I just tried it with Firefox 14.0.1 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have found it. To properly use a silverlight in the firefox browser, in the about:config, position dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.npctrl.dll must be set to true (I had default false). Now these samples works :)

Comment: That's very strange, do you have unusual extensions or such installed?

Comment: I have similar extensions, and it works for me (on another PC, also on 14.0.1).

Comment: At work in firefox 14.0.1 it works for me too out of the box. I really don't think I could have a reason to change this property in the about:config manually at home. But I'm glad it works now, so I can play with silverlight in my main browser.